# Get binding target from source?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a ListView whose ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection. The collection is filled with "WaypointItem" objects (a small class we defined with the info for the listview).

The WaypointItem is our binding source for each row, but is there any magic way to get a reference to all objects (targets) binding to this class from within the WaypointItem code?

Thanks
jason

Comment: This isn't easily possible, but it should rarely be necessary: a key aspect of WPF architecture is that models (data objects, binding sources) shouldn't need to know who's binding to them: that stuff is handled in the view (framework elements, binding targets).  This helps decouple models from views.  So there may be a better way to do what you want.  Could you say what do you want to be able to do with the list of binding targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something helpful in the [BindingOperations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations_members.aspx) class.  Unfortunately the Target of the binding is probably actually the DataContext of the item presenter (if I understand your description correctly), which means your WaypointItem probably can't tell what may be binding to it.

One slightly off-the-wall possibility would be to implement a custom IValueConverter that notifies your WaypointItem through a well-defined interface that it has been bound to something.  It would send this notification on every update, so you would need to handle that appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys!  I was just being lazy, with a bit more code I have no need to reverse these bindings anymore.

Comment: This is an old question, but I just accepted the answer for the link to BindingOperations docs, but also the negative answer ("your WaypointItem probably can't tell what may be binding to it") led me to realize this is not easily possible and that I needed to reconsider the design so "reversing" a binding would not be necessary in the first place.